# How to call Tank Auth hashing function inside my own controller in CodeIgniter?

Tags: codeigniter

I use Tank Auth library on my site and it works great from frontend.

However I want to be able to manage users from admin side of my website, so I need to be able to create a new user via admin.

I would like to use Tank auth's functions to create the password in the same format as phpass in tank auth is using.

So, after successful validation I need to hash $_POST['password'] using Tank Auth function PasswordHash.

So, now I have this code in my controller:

```
$this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
$this->load->library('form_validation');
$this->load->library('security');
$this->load->library('tank_auth');
$this->lang->load('tank_auth');

$password_original = $_POST['password'];

$hasher = new PasswordHash(
    $this->ci->config->item('phpass_hash_strength', 'tank_auth'),
    $this->ci->config->item('phpass_hash_portable', 'tank_auth')
);
$hashed_password = $hasher->HashPassword($password);
```

However I am getting this error message:
**Message: Undefined property: Admin::$ci**

I guess I have to initialize new instance with &ci something, but I don't know how.

Thanks in advance for any help or advice how to do it differently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try removing `->ci`

```
$password_original = $_POST['password'];


$hasher = new PasswordHash(
    $this->config->item('phpass_hash_strength', 'tank_auth'),
    $this->config->item('phpass_hash_portable', 'tank_auth')
);


$hashed_password = $hasher->HashPassword($password);
```